# C# timeout exception not caught

Tags: c#, timeout

I'm reading some data over TCP/IP and for some reason timeout exception is not caught.  Any ideas what's wrong here?

```
try
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer(dcaika);
    timer1.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await HandleTimer();
    timer1.Start();
    memoryRes = dc.readBytes(libnodave.daveFlags, 0, 180, 1, memoryBuffer);
    timer1.Stop();
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
}
```

and here is timeout handling

```
private static Task HandleTimer()
{
    Console.WriteLine("timeout");
    throw new TimeoutException();
}
```

Comment: Is this a typo `catch (TimeoutException )` it shoulfd be `catch (TimeoutException ex)`

Comment: @MairajAhmad You don't need to specify `ex` unless you are planning to use it

Comment: @dotnetom thanks for pointing

Comment: On elapsing of a timer you throw an exception, and you expect to catch that exception in the routine that sets up the timer?

Comment: The Elapsed event handler is not executed int try-catch block. Try creating async wrapper for dc.ReadBytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just not the way .NET events work. They don't interrupt a thread; they'll be run in a context determined by the type of timer it is. In this case (`System.Timers.Timer`), the `Timer.Elapsed` event handler will be invoked on a thread pool thread. So, it's running on a completely different thread than the `try`/`catch`, and that's why it won't work.

It looks like you're trying to force a timeout on an API that doesn't natively support timeouts. There's no clean way to do this. So, the first thing to do is to ask whoever maintains `readBytes` for timeout support.

There *is* a way to do "fake timeouts" like this:

```
var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(dcaika);
var readTask = Task.Run(() => dc.readBytes(libnodave.daveFlags, 0, 180, 1, memoryBuffer));
var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, readTask);
if (completedTask == timeoutTask)
  ...
else
  ...
```

But this approach *will not stop the `readBytes` call*, so it will probably continue reading bytes and mess up your other communications. So I don't think it will work for your scenario.